# In Laravel, what folder should I put a non-public data.json file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

I have another system that will drop in a data.json file *somewhere* onto my Laravel site/folder structure.

I want only Laravel to be able to be able to read the json file (i.e. a user can't see it by typing a url into a browser).

**Where should this file go?**

I'm currently torn between putting it in application/models folder or application/[new folder]. My webroot is set to the public folder, so you can't access the application folder via a browser.

If it is in there, I'm assuming I will be able to read it within php but not javascript (which is okay).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a new folder in the app/ directory. Thats not visible to outsiders. Everything visible is in the public folder, as you said. If you create a new folder you can autoload it by setting up composer.json.

Comment: My understanding is that no folders in the app directory is visible to outsiders?

Comment: The new folder is what I'm thinking as well. I just wanted to make sure Laravel didn't have a recommended area. I haven't seen the composer.json before. I will look into it. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Just keep it out of /public and you will be fine.